# How to convert unorder list in to select option for this

Tags: foreach, drop-down-menu, selection

Hi I am trying to add child category selection list and I found one nice code here and works fine but I want to use it as a dropdown selectoin and not un order list. Can anyone help me to do that.

```
<?php
if (is_category()) {
    $cat = get_query_var('cat');
    $this_category = get_category($cat);
    $this_category = wp_list_categories('hide_empty=0&hierarchical=true&orderby=id&show_count=0&title_li=&use_desc_for_title=1&child_of='.$this_category->cat_ID."&echo=0");
    if($this_category !='<li>No categories</li>')
    {
     echo '<h3>Products</h3>'; 
     echo '<ul>'.$this_category.'</ul>'; 
    }
}
?>
```

I have tried to use foreach but it didnt work may be I am wrong somewhere as not master in php

```
<?php
    if (is_category()) {
        $cat = get_query_var('cat');
        $this_category = get_category($cat);
        $this_category = wp_list_categories('hide_empty=0&hierarchical=true&orderby=id&show_count=0&title_li=&use_desc_for_title=1&child_of='.$this_category->cat_ID."&echo=0");
        if($this_category !='<li>No categories</li>')
        {
            echo '<h3>Products</h3>';
            echo '<select>';
            foreach($this_category as $list) {
            echo '<option>'.$list.'</option>'; 
            }
            echo '</select>';
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Perhaps you can provide the output or the error message that you're getting?

Comment: with un orderlist code I am getting everything works fine but with second code with <option> its rendering only select box but no option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your code doesn't appear to enter the foreach loop.  The variable $this_category seems to be a string, not an array that you can iterate over.

Do a string replace to switch the `<li>` tags with `<option>` and then echo it:

```
$this_category = str_replace('<li>', '<option>', $this_category);
$this_category = str_replace('</li>', '</option>', $this_category);

echo '<select>'.$this_category.'</select>';
```

Comment: Have you tested this code? Just asking so please dont take it otherwise because I have tested but its giving me blank select dropdown.